# Getting Galvanic Skin Response from Microsoft Band via Android SDK

Tags: android, microsoft-band

I'm developing an Android-Band app using the Microsoft SDK in which is not mentioned the possibility to obtain the GSR value (even if the Band includes this sensor). Beside, searching on web, i've found an app (running on Windows Phone) able to show this value, "unlocking" all the "hidden" values of Band's sensors. Is there a chance to achieve a similar result on Android devices?

Link to WP app: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/band-sensor-monitor/68f97b41-de2f-4579-a473-5d476a5c5196

Thank you in advice and sorry for my bad English. I'm new here (even though i've been lurking on this site for a very long time :P)

Answer (score 1):

A GSR not exposed by the SDK. You can add feature requests for future versions of the SDK at: http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Vote it if you can http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band/suggestions/7924716-let-developers-read-galvanic-skin-response-data

Comment: I just voted. Thanks for the link.
By the way ... as OP mentioned, it appears some apps are already able to measure GSR values at this time. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/home?forum=windowssdk&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc .

Is there any particular route needed in order to get approval/access ? This might be worth investigating.

Comment: I've sento sent some emails and asked for more informations on Facebook. I'll let you know if there'll be any updates

Comment: I too would be interested if they write back.

Answer (score 1):

GSR support was included in October update of SDK (https://developer.microsoftband.com/bandSDK) but only for Band 2

> Microsoft Band SDK Release Notes
>
> October 2015: Band SDK update for Windows Phone, Windows, iOS, and
>   Android. New features:
>
> - Works with both Microsoft Band and Microsoft Band 2.
> - Introduces 5 new
>     sensors for Microsoft Band 2.

According to change-list those "5 new sensors" are:

> - MSBSensorAltimeterData
> - MSBSensorAmbientLightData
> - MSBSensorBarometerData
> - MSBSensorGSRData
> - MSBSensorRRIntervalData

[Here](http://msbandguru.com/2015/10/06/microsoft-band-2-brings-updated-sdk-for-developers/) author claims that

> The following 5 new sensors are available with the Band 2 only. As a dev, your app will receive an error if you attempt to use these with a Band 1.

Comment: Actually there is a way to access GSR data on Band 1 but you have to make your own SDK

Comment: Sith, maybe you can say more?